# Can you check the application of second order runge-kutta method?

Tags: python, runge-kutta

```
def second(y, z, y0, z0, t0, tf, dt):
N = (tf-t0)/dt
  y.append(y0)
  for i in range(int(N)):
    t1 = t0 + dt
    y1 = y0 + z0*dt
    zk1 = z(t0, y0, z0)
    zk2 = z(t0+1/2*dt, y0+1/2*dt, z0+1/2*zk1*dt)
    z1 = z0 + zk2*dt
    y.append(y1)
    t0 = t1
    y0 = y1
    z0 = z1
  return y
```

I am getting something like this: [1, 1, -8.0, -26.0, -269.0]. Can you check if I understand how to apply the second order runge-kutta method?

Comment: Could you disentangle the situation a little bit. You are using `z` for the velocity and acceleration function, it is not really clear what method you are trying to use. Is it just the explicit midpoint method with reduction of the linear steps?

Comment: @LutzLehmann it is the second-order differential equation, which is the y''+4y^2=0. So searching the internet I found out that to solve the 2nd order ODE we need to the y'=z and z'= -4y^2

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is more likely to get an answer on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement the explicit midpoint method

```
k1 = f(t,u)
k2 = f(t+dt/2, u+k1*dt/2)
u_next = u+k2*dt
```

for a second order equation `y''=a(t,y,y')`. To that end you set `z=y'` and `u=[y,z]`. In components you get

```
k1y = z
k1z = a(t,y,z)
k2y = z + k1z*dt/2
k2z = a(t+dt/2, y+k1y*dt/2, z+k1z*dt/2)

y_next = y + k2y*dt
z_next = z+k2z*dt
```

Then to use the special structure of the first order system of a second order equation, you eliminate `k1y,k2y` which gives

```
k1z = a(t,y,z)
k2z = a(t+dt/2, y+z*dt/2, z+k1z*dt/2)
y_next = y + z*dt + k1z*dt^2/2
z_next = y + k2z*dt
```

Now, compared to your code, there are several differences.